Подменить данные googleapiclient с помощью unittest
Есть функция, которую нужно протестировать:
def get_id_object_by_name(name: str, folder_id: str = None) -> str:
"""Подключается к Google Drive и получает id папки или файла, по названию,
переданному в аргументе и возвращает его в виде {название: id}."""

service = auth_gdrive()
if folder_id:
    query = f"name = '{name}' and '{folder_id}' in parents"
else:
    query = f"name = '{name}'"
r = service.files().list(pageSize=10,
                         fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)",
                         q=query).execute()
if r["files"]:
    logger.debug(f"Получен id файла {name} в папке с id '{folder_id}'.")
    return r["files"][0]["id"]

else:
    logger.debug(f"id файла {name} в папке {folder_id} не найден. "
                 f"Проверьте наличие файла в папке с id {folder_id} '.")

Я нашел способ подмены ответа запроса в документации гугла:
google-api-python-client
http = HttpMock('books-discovery.json', {'status': '200'})
api_key = 'your_api_key'
service = build('books', 'v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
request = service.volumes().list(source='public', q='android')
http = HttpMock('books-android.json', {'status': '200'})
response = request.execute(http=http)

В файл books-android.json я положил ответ, который я хотел бы получить:
{
    "files": [
        {
            "id": "345245634",
            "name": "main-log-1",
            "mimeType": "text/plain"
        }
    ]
}

И есть сам модуль с тестом:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from google_drive.uploader import get_id_object_by_name
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import HttpMock


class TestGetId(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_id_by_name(self):

        http = HttpMock('books-discovery.json', {'status': '200'})
        api_key = 'your_api_key'
        service = build('books', 'v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
        request = service.volumes().list(source='public', q='android')
        http = HttpMock('books-android.json', {'status': '200'})
        response = request.execute(http=http)

        result = get_id_object_by_name()

Как мне подменить результат ответа API внутри функции get_id_object_by_name()?
Пока что пришел к этому:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from google_drive.uploader import get_id_object_by_name


class TestGetId(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('google_drive.uploader.auth_gdrive')
    def test_get_id_by_name(self, mock_auth_gdrive):
        # Создаем замоканный объект Google Drive API
        mock_service = MagicMock()
        mock_files = MagicMock()
        mock_list_request = MagicMock()

        # Настраиваем цепочку вызовов для auth_gdrive
        mock_auth_gdrive.return_value = mock_service
        mock_service.files.return_value = mock_files
        mock_files.list.return_value = mock_list_request

        http = HttpMock('books-discovery.json', {'status': '200'})
        api_key = 'your_api_key'
        service = build('books', 'v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
        request = service.volumes().list(source='public', q='android')
        http = HttpMock('books-android.json', {'status': '200'})
        response = request.execute(http=http)

        # Указываем, что вернет метод execute()
        mock_list_request.execute.return_value = response

        # Вызываем тестируемую функцию
        result = get_id_object_by_name('main-log-1', 'test_folder')

        # Проверяем результат
        self.assertEqual(result, '345245634', "ID файла должен быть '345245634'")
        self.assertIsInstance(result, str, "Возвращаемое значение должно быть строкой")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

Результат тестов:
python -m unittest
DEBUG:google_drive.uploader:Запуск автозагрузчика...
Данные, возвращаемые функцие get_id_object_by_name: {'files': [{'mimeType': 'text/plain', 'id': '13_Vm_DH-sKuP-wWRTDUuxOPwiq_Q6-FN', 'name': 'main_log_i-analytic7.pz.cp.log'}]}
DEBUG:google_drive.uploader:Получен id файла main_log_i-analytic7.pz.cp.log в папке с id '15U_0EiHwodg1HU-7heyB5fNFWjy8Ua9p'.
13_Vm_DH-sKuP-wWRTDUuxOPwiq_Q6-FN
C:\Users\DOrlov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\unittest\mock.py:2245: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=1356, family=2, type=1, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.104.11', 58355
), raddr=('209.85.233.95', 443)>
  def __init__(self, name, parent):
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\Users\DOrlov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\unittest\mock.py:2245: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=1372, family=2, type=1, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.104.11', 58356
), raddr=('173.194.220.95', 443)>
  def __init__(self, name, parent):
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Данные, возвращаемые функцие get_id_object_by_name: {'files': [{'id': '345245634', 'name': 'main-log-1', 'mimeType': 'text/plain'}]}
DEBUG:google_drive.uploader:Получен id файла main-log-1 в папке с id 'test_folder'.
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.026s

OK

